# How to make evaluating expressions faster under (remote) debugging?

Tags: java, android-studio, intellij-idea, remote-debugging, android-debug

Intellij Idea (Android studio as well) [supports evaluating expressions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/evaluating-expressions.html?origin=old_help) and code fragments in the context of the current stack frame. It is very useful for debugging purposes and works fine with local debugging.

But if I want to evaluate some code under **remote** debugging Java application or Android app on emulator (or a real device), it is evaluating... evaluating... evaluating and so on.[image: evaluating expression]

Usially, first evaluating can take up to 5 minutes. Later evaluatings are immediately executed on the same breakpoint.

(I faced that problem on different machines)

So, anybody knows how can I solve this issue?